# Handling String input in C

Tags: c, char, user-input

If a char array needs to be declared before it is used, how does one declare one so that is can be used to store input?

e.g. The user enters a sentence or series of words. How is this stored so that it can be manipulated?

What is the correct way rather than just declaring an array which is large enough to handle expected input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about **console input**, you have no choice but to have a FIXED SIZE buffer and use a **secure** function not allowing more than `FIXED_SIZE` to be stored on your buffer.

An example would be:

```
char buff[1024];
fgets(buff, 1024, stdin); // to read from standard input
```

You must warn your user that any characters beyond 1023th will be ignored.

If you want to access last character the user entered:

```
printf("%c", buff[strlen(buff)-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks. How does one access the characters then? If the buff is 1024 and e.g the user enters a string of 10 characters, if I wanted to access the last character do I need to iterate through the array to find the escape character? What If I used a pointer? e.g. char *word; and then set word to the input from scanf. How would I access the characters?

Comment: Ok thanks. I dont know why I have this idea that everything needs to be self written in C. :)

Comment: Actually, they'll only be ignored by that particular `fgets`, they'll still be sitting in the input buffer when you come back to do another read, sometimes _very_ annoying :-) You can usually detect if the line was longer than intended and then `getchar` until you read a newline.

Comment: Should fgets be used for taking user input rather than scanf?

Comment: @alJaree: It depends on what you want. If you just want PLAIN INPUT, `fgets`. If you want INPUT+PARSING, `scanf`. Although, you should use `scanf_s` (scanf's secure version).

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz: Btw, the above statement should be printf("%c", buff[strlen(buff)-2]); to print the last character, -1 returns the \n :) thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the following function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

It uses the buffer-overflow-safe `fgets` with some supporting code to figure out if the line you entered was too long.

You can of course, read partial lines and perform memory re-allocations to store an arbitrary sized input string but usually it's more than adequate to just set a large enough upper boundary and allow for that (say 1K for example). If anyone enters more than that for their name or address, they're probably just being silly :-)

I've actually used that trick (partial reads and reallocs) to do user input before but, to be honest, the need for it was so rare that it didn't make it into my "important source code snippets" repository.

The use of `fgets` prevents the possibility of buffer overflow which is the *big* danger to user input.

---

If you want to test that code, try adding:

```
int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        printf ("No input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

and some sample runs:

```
pax> ./qq
Enter string> hi bob
OK [hi bob]

pax> ./qq
Enter string>
No input

pax> ./qq
Enter string> hi ho the merry oh
Input too long
```

(that second one was entering <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, an immediate end of file).

Answer (score 1):

Input via buffer ? ( User writes its text to buffer of some size, when buffer is full, programm changes size of target array using realloc )

( you need to use char* instead of char[] )